# ORA-12505 Listener does not currently know SID descriptor

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'am new in oracle. I have an virtual machine with oracle database. Yesterday everything works fine, but today when i'm trying to connect to db a have an error ORA - 12505.

My listener.ora is(xp is a name of my VM):

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xp)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

My tnsnames is:

```
ORCLMIS =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xp)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

So what can be a problem?

P.S. I'am using Windows XP. And server is on the local machine.

Comment: How are you connecting? SQLPlus? Oracle SQL developer? What did you give the SID as? If you're connecting via TNS of ORCLMIS then it looks for service name of orcl which isn't defined in your listener.ora

Comment: @Sathya I'am connecting via SQL Developer. SID is orcl. And yesterday thats works fine.

Comment: try tnsping. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e41945/connect.htm#NETAG357
If tnsping doesn't return OK, then some of your tns parameters have changed from yesterday, you should check them

Comment: Are you sure the database is up? The TNS alias is connecting by service name, not SID, and you don't have a SID specified in the listener.ora. But if you're specifying the host, port and SID explicitly in the SQL Developer connection then the tnsnames.ora isn't relevant. Have you changed that connection from service name to SID by mistake?

Comment: @AlexPoole Thank you. Change connection to service name help. But it a little bit strange becouse yesterday I was using SID to connect.